# Okta Tutorial: appBaseUrl is missing

Tags: node.js, express, okta

Was following this Okta with expressjs tutorial to create a simple authentication using both(https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/31/simple-auth-express-fifteen-minutes), and ended up cloning the repo to work on it. Installed the packages, but when running `npm start` it threw some errors. So I decided to install the latest version of each package. Tried running the project again but this time this error popped up:

```
> okta_tutorial@1.0.0 start /Users/tomas/Documents/software/okta_tutorial
> nodemon .

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node .`
/Users/tomas/Documents/software/okta_tutorial/node_modules/@okta/configuration-validation/dist/lib.js:144
    throw new ConfigurationValidationError('Your appBaseUrl is missing.');
    ^

Error: Your appBaseUrl is missing.
    at new ConfigurationValidationError (/Users/tomas/Documents/software/okta_tutorial/node_modules/@okta/configuration-validation/dist/lib.js:29:141)
    at configUtil.assertAppBaseUrl (/Users/tomas/Documents/software/okta_tutorial/node_modules/@okta/configuration-validation/dist/lib.js:144:11)
    at new ExpressOIDC (/Users/tomas/Documents/software/okta_tutorial/node_modules/@okta/oidc-middleware/src/ExpressOIDC.js:79:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tomas/Documents/software/okta_tutorial/index.js:24:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have a Base URL for Okta Developer that looks like `https://dev-xxxxxx.okta.com`.

My `.env` file is also present with all the required info from the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this error

### Solution number 1

Add the `appBaseUrl` property to the object you are passing to the ExpressOIDC

```
const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
  appBaseUrl: process.env.OKTA_BASEAPP_URL,
  issuer: process.env.OKTA_DOMAIN,
  client_id: process.env.OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: process.env.OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirect_uri: process.env.OKTA_REDIRECT_URL,
  scope: process.env.OKTA_SCOPE
});
```

### Solution number 2

the first one is to downgrade the version of `@okta/oidc-middleware` to `1.0.2`

First remove the node packages

```
$ rm -rf ./node_modules
```

Second, in your package.json change the version of `@okta/oidc-middleware` to `1.0.2`

Third install the node modules

```
$ npm install
```